# React-native installing required CocoaPods dependencies stuck

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

i cant finish react-native init as the process keep stuck at instaling required cocoapods dependencies please help

this is a few part what shown in terminal:

```
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 48 new dependencies.
├─ @babel/core@7.5.0
├─ @babel/runtime@7.5.0
├─ @react-native-community/eslint-config@0.0.5
├─ @types/eslint-visitor-keys@1.0.0
├─ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.11.0
├─ @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@1.11.0
├─ @typescript-eslint/parser@1.11.0
├─ @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.11.0
├─ acorn-jsx@5.0.1
├─ acorn@6.2.0
├─ ajv@6.10.0
├─ babel-jest@24.8.0
├─ chardet@0.7.0
├─ doctrine@3.0.0
├─ emoji-regex@7.0.3
├─ eslint-scope@4.0.3
├─ eslint-utils@1.3.1
├─ eslint@6.0.1
├─ espree@6.0.0
├─ esquery@1.0.1
├─ external-editor@3.0.3
├─ file-entry-cache@5.0.1
├─ flat-cache@2.0.1
├─ flatted@2.0.1
├─ functional-red-black-tree@1.0.1
├─ glob-parent@3.1.0
├─ ignore@4.0.6
├─ import-fresh@3.1.0
├─ inquirer@6.4.1
├─ is-extglob@2.1.1
├─ is-glob@4.0.1
├─ jest@24.8.0
├─ json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@1.0.1
├─ levn@0.3.0
├─ lodash.unescape@4.0.1
├─ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.55.0
├─ optionator@0.8.2
├─ parent-module@1.0.1
├─ path-dirname@1.0.2
├─ progress@2.0.3
├─ react-refresh@0.2.0
├─ regexpp@2.0.1
├─ rxjs@6.5.2
├─ table@5.4.1
├─ text-table@0.2.0
├─ tslib@1.10.0
├─ tsutils@3.14.0
└─ write@1.0.3
✨  Done in 19.41s.
info Installing required CocoaPods dependencies
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Installing required CocoaPods dependencies` takes time. Waiting for about 30mins worked for me.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem.  Does this mean every time we want to create a react-native project we really have to wait 30-40 minutes???  Is there no smarter solution?

Comment: Hi, @preston My subsequent projects were faster. Once you have `CocoaPods` installed you should be good. I hope that helps and answers your question.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is necessarily true. I was able to install CocoaPods using `sudo gem install cocoapods` in only a minute or two. Trying to install it via the react-native package hung for 45 minutes for me.

Answer (score 16):

Waiting for about 40mins worked for me. Installing required CocoaPods dependencies takes time. See my screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 13):

Break with Ctrl-C.

---

Enter *cd ios*

---

Run *pod install --repo-update*

---

But anyway it is not fast. Need wait because big repo cloned into fs under the hood.

Comment: Suggestion: run `pod install --repo-update --verbose`, that way you can actually see what's going on and be reassured that it's not stuck, just very slow.

Answer (score 6):

**Install CocaPods** 
CocoaPods is a package management tool for iOS and macOS development. We use it to add the actual React Native framework code locally into your current project.

We recommend installing CocoaPods using Homebrew.

```
$ brew install cocoapods
```

or

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: when i try that, my terminal said i have already installed cocoapods.

Comment: Can i do react-native init without that cocoapod installation process?

Comment: have You installed Node 10+ , you can use npm to install the Expo CLI command line utility:
`npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: Thankyou, my problem is solved. Installation process of cocoapod is long. I wait for about 1 hour and its done.

Comment: i tried above and it didnt work ... then i tried with just a little bit of change in command "sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin" which i think related to location of installation and availability on path, which i found posted in another thread. and it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Fixed with this - Open Xcode and go to Xcode → Preferences → Locations, and make sure the command line tools is set to the version of Xcode you’re using.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on MacOS 11.2.1

Comment: Very weird - I just had to open XCode to kick this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable iCloud, this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Solved by changing my internet connection from WIFI to mobile data. Then I ran the following commands which worked for me:

```
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod install
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

It took a while for CocoaPods installation and I got error at the end. `podfile` was inside iOS folder with no `.xcworkspace`. I did `pod install` again (in iOS folder) and all good. Please make sure CocoaPods is installed.

Answer (score -1):

I think the main problem is mismatch version of CocoaPods and react native dependency. So you can try update Cocoapods

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

and then go inside your react native project in `/ios` folder then install pod again with

`pod install`